# Accessing element value based on XML tag Value

Tags: xml, python-3.x

How can i access the element's actual value in XML file.
Now i am able to print the list of elements but the locating of the tags is problematic

```
print(root.findall('.//ns:HomeTown',namespaces=ns))

[<Element HomeTown at 0x1d4bb9e9208>, <Element HomeTown at 0x1d4bb9e91c8>]
```

I am able to locate the correct elements but was not able to print it out.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I think your post would be more useful if you could provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was just .text missing

```
for xmlField in root.findall('.//ns:HomeTown',namespaces=ns):
    print(xmlField.text)
```

After that looping through all "HomeTown" fields and then printing the value of that tag.